# Accessing class and id in divs

Tags: css

How do I access the last div (div.access-example) in this line of code?

```
<div id="footer-example" class="full-example">

   <div id="footer-example2" class="fixed-example">

       <div class="almost-there">

          <div class="access-example">
```

I tried it like this:

```
div#footer-example div#footer-example2 div.almost-there div.access-example
{ code goes here; }
```

When that didn't work, I added `{ code goes here !important;}` in case something was overriding it. I also tried with children (`>`).

Note: I can't use `div.access-example` and add my code because the same div is being used elsewhere, and I need to change it only in that particular place; and because it's a Wordpress site and I don't have access to the Ftp, I need to access nested divs.

Comment: `.full-example > .fixed-example > .almost-there > .access-example` try this

Comment: Why not `#footer-example .access-example`?

Comment: Or, perhaps, just `.access-example`. Shorter CSS selectors are better CSS selectors.

Comment: `#footer-example2 .access-example`

Comment: @RyanKinal He already mentioned that he cannot use like that since he is using the same class in somewhere else.

Comment: Ah. Yep. Missed that bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works..

```
#footer-example #footer-example2 .almost-there .access-example {
    color:red;
}
```

This also works

```
#footer-example .fixed-example .almost-there .access-example {
    color:red;
}
```

Make sure this (your) `CSS` declaration is not being overridden using Chrome Dev Tools or something similar.

Comment: That makes sense, so I tried it like this: #footer-wrapper .full-width-wrapper .fixed-width-wrapper .one-third.first .one-third. It doesn't work, tho. I also tried it with children (>). I'm doing this in the web browser console window, but I don't see why it should matter. As soon as I only focus on the last class, it works.

Comment: It works now. What I needed to do was to cut the first id and just go with the last three classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
div div div .access-example
{
background-color:yellow;
}
```

or

```
#footer-example #footer-example2 .almost-there .access-example
{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

You can vary by removing one of the class or id in the 2nd.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to call the `.access-example` class, you can do this:

```
.access-example{}
```

If you need to have the hierarchy, this works too:

```
.full-example > .fixed-example > .almost-there > .access-example{}
```